# How to Pass a VueComponent to the $vuetify.goTo() method?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i have 3 view components named home, about & work. in App.vue file

```
<v-app>
    <ToolBar />
    <v-content>
      <router-view name="home"></router-view>
      <router-view name="about"></router-view>
      <router-view> </router-view>
    </v-content>
</v-app>
```

router.js file contains this.

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: {
        home: Home,
        about: About
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/work',
      name: 'work',
      component: () => import('./views/work/Work.vue')
    }
  ]
})
```

in About.vue file

```
<template>
    <div id="about">
        <v-container>
            ....
        </v-container>
    </div>
</template>
```

and in ToolBar.vue file

```
<v-btn @click="$vuetify.goTo('#about', options)">About</v-btn>
```

let's say i'm in the '/' route (path) and i clicked the about button in toolbar. It then scroll down to About component as expected. What i want is to do when i am on route '/work' and clicked the about button, go to home page '/' and scroll down to the about section.

In vuetify documentation, it says `goTo(target: string | number | HTMLElement | VueComponent, options?: object) => void`.

My first question is that how to Pass a Vue Component as an argument to the goTo method target parameter?

Second question is that if this is the best way to achieve the behavior i wanted? if not how to get the result i expected?

"English is not my first language, please edit for clarity, then remove this comment!"

Answer (score 13):

First you need to set an id in the component

```
<about id='about'/>
```

from the button call the component id

```
<v-btn @click="$vuetify.goTo('#about')">About</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass the target as a VueComponent, use `ref` on the desired target to let you pass it as an argument to `goTo`.

```
<about ref='about'/>
```

from button:

```
<v-btn @click="$vuetify.goTo(this.$refs.about)">About</v-btn>
```