# Can I programmatically get a Vue Component's id in Vue2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

So, I've got a `VueComponent` and the goal is to pass it to `$vuetify.goTo()` so that the page scrolls to that component. Unfortunately, `$vuetify.goto()` expects a selector or a ref (Even though its error message says it accepts a `VueComponent`).

I've given each possible `VueComponent` an id, but the problem is, I don't know how to get the id programmatically. I tried `component.$el.id`, but I keep getting `undefined`.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Pass a VueComponent to the $vuetify.goTo() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54070317/how-to-pass-a-vuecomponent-to-the-vuetify-goto-method)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I saw that question, but the problem is that there are multiple components which could be the one passed to `goto()`, so I need to be able to find the id of that one programmatically.

Comment: your question is alittle unclear, if you're doing goto within the page its trivial, follow the docs or the linked post, but sounds like something different `this._uid` is unique, how about putting `:id="_uid"` on the component, then it will be `this.$vuetify.goto(this._uid)`, if you have multiple on a single page then concat some string at the front, if its from some parent then call a method on the child like `this.$refs.something.gotoTo('#section_2')`, then concat the value to `where+this._uid`, an example of the issue would help

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get the functionality that I was looking for by using

```
vueComponent.$el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center" });
```

Instead of:

```
this.$vuetify.goTo(vueComponent);
```